# ASP.NET and multi-threaded background workers

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, hangfire

I'm developing a web application that can send mass emails in background.

To run the task in background I'll use either HostingEnviroment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem or some library such as Hangfire. As I want my mailer to run its job as fast as possible I use multi-threading so the main thread being run under the tools above also creates a number of new threads. It's known that ASP.NET can killbackground workers for many reasons.

1. What is the order the .NET kills all these threads?
2. Is there way for parent/child thread to know the child/parent thread being aborted?
3. How much time do I have to handle ThreadAbortException in these threads before .NET shuts it down completely?

Comment: I regularly hand off 5000 emails to a web service that sends them via an Exchange box. 5000 usually takes 4 or 5 minutes. If the user checks on the status of their send I just show them '2475 of 5000 have been processed' ... if they are that interested.

Comment: For question 2: There is no such parent/child relationship in threads.

Comment: Typically people write windows services to accomplish this.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse i beleive the sending takes 5 mins, but even here there is a chance for process to be interrupted (power off, .NET clean uo etc). For "parent/child" I meant the parent is that who starts the "child"

Comment: @SriramSakthivel with the tools above there should be a way with no windows service

Comment: There is no guarantee that the work handed off to the Queue will ever be executed. If guaranteed execution is a requirement then DO NOT use this new utility!

Comment: If it has to be reliable then AFAIK you have to store somewhere (DB, for example) what you have to do. You pop, you send and then you delete from queue. Anything else can be interrupted (even if single threaded). Moreover if you send to the same server it will limit number of concurrent connection from same IP so you may not have any great benefit to span your task in more than 3 or 4 threads.

Comment: @RobEpstein what about HangFire?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I know. My question is what's the logic and the order the threads under .NET are interrupted and what timeout do I have to handle it.

Comment: HangFire uses SQL Server as a backing store for queued work so they can guarantee execution. If that is what you require then I would select HangFire over QueueBackgroundWorkItem. If guaranteed execution isn't a requirement then the lighter weight QueueBackgroundWorkItem would be the appropriate choice.

Comment: Still, all this said, this should really be a windows service!!

Comment: I have spawned threads within ASP.NET apps in IIS for quick low-priority tasks that had no state.  For example, to cleanup temp files from a fixed folder location.  It made deployment really easy because there was no service to create.  I needed one on each server anyway.  I didn't care if IIS aborted it, or even if it didn't run for days.  But I would not use this for something like emailing.  What if IIS started two instances of your ASP.NET app and thus two instances of your emailer?  What if it aborts or goes down for a while?  Use a service.